# SQL Server: Script all DB objects (SP, Tables, Triggers, etc.) to SQL script

Tags: sql-server

I would like to ask the experts here on how to script the database objects in SQL Server 2008 Express Edition. When generating scripts, I found out that only tables and triggers are available to be script. But how can the SPs be scripted too?

The problem is that I have a host provider and I wanted the database in my site to have ASP.NET membership framework objects (tables, SPs). It is a big disadvantage because my host does not allow remote access to their SQL Server.

I wanted my site's database to have objects of ASP.NET membership framework. What they allow is SQL scripts using "my little admin" tools.

Any help will be appreciated. If my question is not clear enough, please post a comment so I may revise the question.

Thanks!

Comment: plesae specify your SQL Server version...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this answer: [Script all stored procedures in Management Studio 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175703/script-all-stored-procedures-in-management-studio-2005)

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted my site's database to have
>   objects of ASP.NET membership
>   framework.

You can check out aspnet_regsql.exe command, which allows you to create all  ASP.NET membership objects (tables/stored procedures) in the target database.

Also check out the [Microsoft SQL Server Database Publishing Wizard](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=56E5B1C5-BF17-42E0-A410-371A838E570A&displaylang=en)