# Backup Stored Procedures

Tags: stored-procedures, backup, ssms

Currently, if I want to make a backup of a stored procedure, using Mircosoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2, I right click on my stored procedure, choose modify and then in the stored procedure change alter proc part to create proc, and add the word "backup" to the end of the name of the stored procedure.  Is there a better way to do this?  In a perfect world, I would like to be able to backup all the stored procedures in a database and keep them maybe somewhere locally. I don't like how my list of stored procedures is getting sloppy (for lack of a better word) with all these backups I have made.  If you can't tell, I am exteremly new to writing stored procedures and want to be able to have this to safeguard the existing stored procedures from any mistakes I might make.

Thanks in advance for all your help!

Comment: Try this SO post for ideas. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183148/stored-procedure-versioning

Comment: One more stackoverflow answer which I prefer - [Script all stored procedures in Management Studio 2005](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175703/script-all-stored-procedures-in-management-studio-2005).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways to keep backups of your stored procedures apart from your live database.  Here are just a few:

- When you backup your database, all the stored procedures are included in that backup.  If you need to revert to an older version, you can restore to another database and script the procedure to a new editor tab or file or whatever.  Hopefully, you have a live and test database anyway, so you could just go to your live database and script the stored procedure there rather than having to restore from backup.
- You can script each version of your stored procedure to separate files as you create them and name and append a date to the name of the file.  You can script all existing stored procedures by looking at the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175703/script-all-stored-procedures-in-management-studio-2005?lq=1) question.
- You can use a version control product.  I'm not sure if I'm allowed to point you to one here, but just do a search on "SQL source control" and you will find a very good one in the search results.