# SQL Server 2012 : How to script all database stored procedures into separate .sql files?

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, sql-scripts, generate-scripts

I want to script all the stored procedures from SQL Server 2012 to Visual Studio 2012 as  `.sql` files (in a different project). How do I do that?  I want one .sql file for each stored procedure? 
I get the scripts using the Generate Scripts in Tasks option after right clicking DB in SQL Server 2012. However, the name of the .sql file is spname.StoredProcedure in each case. I want the name to be spname.sql. 
Again I don't want the file name to be database.spname.StoredProcedure, I want it to be just spname.sql

Comment: go to SSMS, right click database, choose scripting tasks, check your SPs and set up scripting options

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Script all stored procedures in Management Studio 2005](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175703/script-all-stored-procedures-in-management-studio-2005)

Comment: I want one .sql file for each stored procedure, and almost get it but the name of the files is spname.StoredProcedure, I want it to be spname.sql

Answer (score 9):

Please check following SQL tutorial showing how to [generate a separate script file for each stored procedure in a SQL Server database](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/bcp-and-sp_helptext-to-script-store-procedures-into-seperate-files.aspx)

The solution uses sp_Helptext stored procedure with SQL BCP command for generating create script for target SP and then create the export .sql file on the file system.

I hope it helps,

[image]

Additionally on generate script wizard, if you configure selection options as seen in below picture, you will get the sp name as the output script file name

[image]

Comment: I tried the above way to script @Eralper , but I get an error -- The text for object 'spname' is encrypted.

Comment: This is because that stored procedure named "spname" is encrypted. It is not possible to view contents of that procedure. I'm not sure if there is a way to see it. Can you see its content manually?

Comment: Yes using a third party app though, red gate @Eralper

Comment: After your comment I tried the dbForge SQL Decryptor tool which worked great :) and free to download and use: https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqldecryptor/

Answer (score 8):

As @Ivan_Starostin said:

**Step one**

[image]

**Step two**

[image]

**Step three**

[image]

Comment: Although the question titled as single sql file, when read carefully Anil wants one file for each stored procedure

Comment: I want one .sql file for each stored procedure, and almost get it but the name of the files is spname.StoredProcedure, I want it to be spname.sql

Comment: Is somebody going to answer my question? I don't want the file names to be dbname.spname.Stored Procedure. I want the names to be spname.sql.

Comment: Hi Anil, I missed the option "Single file per object" on "Files to generate". If you select that option and provide the path only below you will get what you expect.

Comment: Thanks! This did exactly what I was looking for!