# Source Control for legacy SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, tfs, database-project

We a project to rewrite a legacy system built on SQL Server. The system is making use of various databases (+-10) and the related SQL code in them (sp, functions,...). The challenge for me at the moment is to get these databases in source control (TFS).
Have tried to make use of a Visual Studio Database project, looked very promising at the beginning but after we added most of the databases, the VS project got unusably slow or VS 2017 just crashes.

We split the databases into different solutions, this at least stopped VS from crashing, but the speed is still a very big issue. 
Is there a way to speed things up? Have searched, but could not find any way of disabling some of the VS synchronization checks, that I assume in the cause for the slow speed.

My worry is that the compare needed from the DBA team later in the process to build the dacpac or just change SQL will take too long. Looking for a better solution that is suitable for production deployments?

Comment: Have you considered using Git for versioning your SQL scripts/code?  I have seen Git used very effectively with SQL just as with other types of source code.

Comment: Have recommended the change already, not sure however if it will improve the vs database project problem.

Comment: How many objects do the databases contain? I use SSDT without experiencing these sort of problems. Do your databases contain an unusually large number of objects?

Comment: How many tables and sql objects are you talking about here? We are doing something similar for our db with about 200 +- 50 tables and may be 1.5k+ sps. We don't have that thing fully working yet, but haven't noticed it to be unusably slow. VS2017 does crashes though..

Comment: The databases do have an unusually large number of objects. The primary database has more than 1500 tables, plus all the related stored procedures... Hence the reason for the project to correct it. Seems most of these solutions aren't built for this number of objects.

Comment: Is the goal to specifically to get everything into source control one time? Or to constantly sync whatever the server versions are with what you have in source control (which is what all the slow down/crashing you're seeing now is doing). If you know (by convention) that the source control versions will always be the most recent version(s) you can use SSMS Object Browser > Right Click DB > Tasks > Generate Scripts to get everything once then load/attach local files to TFS/VS Projects/etc. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/175710/804797

Comment: The plan is to get everything in source control, and from that point, it should be the source for any changes. The idea is not to just do a check-in at certain intervals from production.